# How to iterate through each column and convert to dictionary, where one of the columns is a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

Dataframe:

[image: dataframe example]

I want to convert this into a nested dictionary that groups by the unique id (00#) or name like:

```
{001:{Bob:{[a,b]:text},{Sky:{[a,d]:text}}, 002:{Ed:{[c,a]:text},{Jed:{[c,a]:text}}}
```

note: I have a function which accomplishes most of this, but run into an error as one of the column is a column of lists. It would also help to know how to iterate through the column of lists and transform each row into a tuple --> [a,b] to (a,b)

Comment: Lists can't be keys of dicts. So `{["a","b"]: "text"}` can't work. Should it just be a string that looks like a list, e.g. `{"[a,b]": "text"}` ?

Comment: or use tuples, they can be used as key

Answer (score 0):

Taking the comments of @user17242583 and @Andrea into account, you can create a nested dictionary with tuples as the keys. You can groupby `col1` and then iterate through each of the rows in the groupby DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['001','002','001','001','002','001'], 'col2': ['Bob','Ed','Lin','Joe','Jed','Sky'],'col3':[['a','b'],['c','a'],['a','c'],['d','b'],['c','a'],['a','d']],'col4':['text','text1','text2','text2','text1','text']})

nested_dict = {}
for group_name,df_group in df.groupby(['col1']):
    inner_dict = {}
    for row in df_group.itertuples(index=False):
        inner_dict[row.col2] = {tuple(row.col3):row.col4}
    nested_dict[group_name] = inner_dict
```

nested_dict:

```
>>> nested_dict
{'001': {'Bob': {('a', 'b'): 'text'}, 'Lin': {('a', 'c'): 'text2'}, 'Joe': {('d', 'b'): 'text2'}, 'Sky': {('a', 'd'): 'text'}}, '002': {'Ed': {('c', 'a'): 'text1'}, 'Jed': {('c', 'a'): 'text1'}}}
```